# How do I simulate "Wish List" and "Bug List" in JIRA workflow?

Tags: workflow, jira

How do I simulate "Wish List" and "Bug List" in JIRA workflow?
Should they be states, or resolutions?

"Wish List" and "Bug List" issues start as regular bugs (or features). They end up on the bug list/wish list after being resolved as Won't Fix. For example this bug will not be fixed in the next release. We don't know in which release in will be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

You could use both. that depends on your needs, and how you would like to set up your workflow.

If you choose the `resolution` field, once an issue is marked as `Won't Fix` you could filter it out from your list of issues. to get the list of all issues with `Won't Fix` you could use the followint JQL:

```
project = TEST AND resolution = "Won't Fix" and issuetype = Bug
project = TEST AND resolution = "Won't Fix" and issuetype = "Feature Request"
```

Once ready to work on that issue, you could change the `resolution` to `open` or something like that, to make it active again. To control when the users can set an issue to `Won't Fix` or `Open` you need to show/hide this field in the related screens.

On the other hand, by using a `Won't Fix` as a status, the filtering of issues is similar:

```
project = TEST AND status = "Won't Fix" and issuetype = "Feature Request"
```

To allow the users to be able so set the issue to `Won't Fix` status from a give status you need to create transitions from the first status to  `Won't Fix` . As well, you need to create transitions from the `Won't Fix` status outward to any status you want the issue to go to next.

Basically, the main difference is not by marking the issues as `Won't Fix`, but in clearing that mark. In the first method, the issue status doesn't have to change, so once the `Won't Fix` will be changes the issue can return to be active from his current status. In the second method all issues will be in the same status, without any relation to which status they used to have, and all of them will be able to go to the same statuses.

Answer (score 0):

Issue Types. Use "Bug" for Bugs and "New Feature" or "Improvement" for the wish list issues. Setting a resolution on a JIRA issue tells JIRA that no further work will be done on that issue. The Fix Version field with a version of "Future" is a better way of keeping an issue active but out of your active lists.

Setting the resolution to Won't Fix will make some of JIRA's gadgets produce unwanted results.

Comment: Usually `New Feature` is not the same as a `Bug`,  `New Feature` is something that doesn't exists while `bug` is a problem with something that already exists. Moving issues between the two in most cases is not recommended, since usually each will have different fields and moving them will cause losing the non-matching fields. Mixing them is not a good idea...

Answer (score 0):

We will try to simulate "Wish List" and "Bug List" using "Deferred" milestone.

Comment: What do you mean by "Deferred" milestone?