# How do I simulate "Withdrawn by reporter" in JIRA workflow?

Tags: workflow, jira

How do I simulate "Withdrawn by reporter" in JIRA workflow? Should it be a resolution?

Comment: Sounds like a resolution to me. You can have a transition named "Withdrawn" that sets the resolution to make it even easier. Adding a new status would seem a bit heavyweight for most cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on your workflow and your needs. The arguments to whether use status or transition are the same as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11750190/how-do-i-simulate-wish-list-and-bug-list-in-jira-workflow).

I would have done is using a [global transition](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Configuring+Workflow#ConfiguringWorkflow-Usingthe%27GlobalTransitions%27panel) that leads to 'Withdrawn' status. This way you could access the list of withdrawn issues easily as well as allowing moving to this status from every other status.

**EDIT**

The big benefit of this method is that all issues that are `Withdrawn by reporter` will all be in the same status, meaning that all of them will have the same path of workflow leading them back to `open` status, making it easier to add specific screens for `Withdrawn by reporter` issues. For example you could add a `reason for re-opening` field.

As i see it , changing the resolution alone is not suffice since i don't see the reason of leaving `Withdrawn by reporter` issues in the same status as other regular issues, i belive it will be wiser to set them apart. This way it will be easier to get reports and queries of `Withdrawn by reporter` issues.

Buy the way,  to get the list of all issues that were in the `Withdrawn by reporter` status use the following JQL:

```
status was "Withdrawn by reporter"
```